# Triggering a new workflow from another workflow?

Tags: github-actions

Can I trigger a new workflow from another workflow?

I'm trying to run a workflow after the first workflow has pushed a new release and it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows):

> An action in a workflow run can't trigger a new workflow run. For example, if an action pushes code using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

EDIT:
The quote above might be confusing. When I add a [Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to the checkout action with `repo` permissions granted (and not repository's GITHUB_TOKEN), the following commands DO trigger other workflows:

```
        - name: Checkout Repo
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          with:
              token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
```

(In my case, running semnatic-release after this checkout, which creates a new release with a new tag - did trigger another workflow that runs only if a tag was created)

Comment: The `GITHUB_TOKEN` that the documentation mentions is the default token scoped to just that repository. What you are using is not *the* `GITHUB_TOKEN`, it's a Personal Access Token (PAT), which has much wider scope. It is intentional that PATs allow further workflows to trigger, while the `GITHUB_TOKEN` does not.

Comment: Thanks @peterevans! yes I used the PAT. I'll fix to 'Personal Access Token (PAT)'

Comment: I have that same scenario and use PAT tokens, but my tags workflow will not run.

Comment: @peterevans to your knowledge is to possible to reduce the PAT scope so that further workflows are not triggered from one workflow?

Comment: @n1nsa1d00 I'm not aware of that being possible. It's not configurable with a scope. If you don't want further workflows triggered then just use the default `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Answer (score 12):

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698892/4964553), you can trigger another workflow using the [`workflow_run` event](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run).

For example we could think of two workflow definitions like this (the only prerequisite is, that both reside in the same repository - but I am sure, there's also an event for other repos as well):

`release.yml`

```
name: CI release

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Release artifact
      run: ...
```

`do-something-different.yml`

```
name: Do anything after the release of the first workflow

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI release"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Do something
        run: ...
```

A crucial point here is that the `name: CI release` definition of the first yaml file must exactly match the `workflow_run: workflows: ["CI release"]` definition in the second yaml file. Another point is that this approach needs to be done on the default branch (which is mostly `main` or `master`) [as the docs state](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run):

> Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file
> is on the default branch.

Comment: Sadly i think `workflow_run` is pretty much useless in most situations:
1. It runs on default branch which is problematic sometimes
2. When triggered from a pull_request workflow it looses the pull_request context and "just runs" and is unaware of the PR

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a general Personal Access Token (which has access to **all** of your repos), you can generate a dedicated SSH keypair for this purpose and add it to the repository as a [Deploy Key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys). This is done as follows:

1. Generate an SSH keypair:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -N "" -f deploy_key -C "github-actions"
   ```
2. Add the private key (generated file `deploy_key`) as an [encryped secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository), e.g. `COMMIT_KEY` to the GitHub project.

   [image: GitHub secret]
3. Add the public key (generated file `deploy_key.pub`) as a [deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#setup-2) with write access to the GitHub project. Tick the `Allow write access` checkbox.

   [image: Deploy key]
4. When checking out the source code in your workflow, add the SSH key:

   ```yaml
   - name: Checkout
     uses: actions/checkout@v3
     with:
       ssh-key: "${{secrets.COMMIT_KEY}}"
   ```

Subsequent push actions in the same workflow will then trigger any configured GitHub workflow as if they were pushed manually.

Answer (score 0):

My Case:

Frontend Branch( 1st Workflow)
Backend Branch (2nd Workflow)

I Wanted to trigger 2nd Workflow from 1st Workflow(here i was pushing some files to backend branch)

Intially used github token to achieve but found it will not work as it doesn't have priviledges.

I used PAT or Deploy token to acheive this

If using PAT token, then in WORKflow 1

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        persist-credentials: false
```

......
.....

..

```
- name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

If using Deploy
(first create SSh keys)

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    ssh-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    persist-credentials: true
```

.....  ..
.....

```
- name: Push changes
  uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
  with:
    ssh: true
    branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

For More  [REF HERE](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-push)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `workflow_run` is what Github calls "reusable workflows". (terrible name IMO)

Reusable workflows are specified "forwards", meaning flow1 explicitly kicks off flow2. In contrast, `workflow_run` is specified "backwards", meaning the 2nd flow says "I should run after flow1", and if you're looking at flow1, there's no indicator that flow2 runs after it.

The Github docs for reusable workflows are here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

But those docs aren't structured well, IMO. I found them hard to use.

Here's a simple example that also passes a string:

```
# Workflow 1: ./.github/workflows/workflow1.yml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  call-workflow2:
    # This must be specified at the job level, not the step level
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow2.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
        FOO: bar
```

```
# Workflow 2: ./.github/workflows/workflow2.yml
on:
  workflow_call:
    # This example has flow2 define its inputs,
    # which is better for matrix strategies.
    # If you prefer to have flow1 define outputs, check the docs for an example.
    inputs:  
      FOO:
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  workflow2-job:
    <job>
```

To be clear, there are a lot of different options for flows & jobs interacting with each other. I found this option perfect for my particular use case, but I wouldn't use it all the time.