# Github Actions - trigger another action after one action is completed

Tags: github, github-actions

I have one action (a `yaml` file) for deploying a docker image to Google Cloud Run.

I would like to receive Slack or Email messages informing the build and push results.

How could the message action be triggered after build action is completed?

Is it possible to get the result of the build action?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

There are 2 options of doing this:

1. Use **a second job inside the same `workflow.yml`** together with **[the `needs` keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)**
2. Create **a separate `notify.yml` workflow** that uses [the **`workflow_run` event** as a trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)

---

**1. Same workflow, separate job with `needs` keyword**

In your `workflow.yml` file you simply define two jobs like this (leveraging the `needs: build` configuration in the second job):

```
name: CI build and notify

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Deploy Docker image to Google Cloud Run
      run: ...

  notify:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Notify Slack and send eMail
        run: ...
```

[As the docs state](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds), the second `notify` job will only start if the first `build` job succeeded:

> Identifies any jobs that must complete successfully before this job
> will run.

Here's a screenshot of how this approach can look like practically [from my own project](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter) (I have a second `publish-snapshot` job instead of your `notify` job - but the concept stays the same):

[image: build-job-triggers-publish-job]

There's also [a way to always let the `notify` job run](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-not-requiring-dependent-jobs-to-be-successful), even if the `build` job failed. You have to enhance the `needs` with a `if: always()` configuration then.

---

**2. Separate workflow, using [the `workflow_run` event as a trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)**

Using the [`workflow_run` event as a trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) we end up having 2 separate GitHub Actions workflow yaml files:

`build.yml`

```
name: CI build

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Deploy Docker image to Google Cloud Run
      run: ...
```

`notify.yml`

```
name: CI notify

# Only trigger, when the build workflow succeeded
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI build"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Notify Slack and send eMail
        run: ...
```

A crucial point here is that the `name: CI build` definition of the first yaml file must exactly match the `workflow_run: workflows: ["CI build"]` definition in the second yaml file. Another point is that this approach needs to be done on the default branch (which is mostly `main` or `master`) [as the docs state](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run):

> Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file
> is on the default branch.

Here's also a [full example project](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml) using the 1st option if you're interested.

Comment: The first approach (_with same workflow, separate job with needs keyword_) would not address the problem described: **I would like to receive Slack or Email messages informing the build results** as the dependent _notify_ job will **only** be triggered when the _build_ job succeeds but will not be triggered when it fails.

Comment: Yeah, but as I wrote beneath the first approaches screenshot: 
"There's also [a way to always let the `notify` job run](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-not-requiring-dependent-jobs-to-be-successful), even if the `build` job failed. You have to enhance the `needs` with a `if: always()` configuration then." So using `if: always()` right before the `needs: build` will do the trick also with the first approach.

Comment: I would use workflow_dispatch rather than using workflow_run... Depends on the control u need when calling notify.yml... if I need to supply some values the next workflow i don't think it's possible via workflow_run...

Comment: `workflow_dispatch` is [a action you need to manually trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch). That's an interesting approach I use myself in other contexts (e.g. release processes) - see this example https://github.com/jonashackt/github-actions-release-maven . But I guess it's not relevant in this very Q&A since the question was: "How could the message action be triggered after build action is completed?". This can't be done with the `workflow_dispatch` event because of it's manual nature.

Comment: Note that `workflow_run: completed` works regardless of upstream workflow failed or not.

Comment: Per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows you need to add `if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}` if you only want to trigger the workflow on the *success* of the first.

Comment: Doea the second approach runs the workflows in different hardware or they are the same? Are the changes made with the first workflow are applied when the second runs?

Comment: By `different hardware` you mean `different virtual machine` I guess? Yeah, using the second approach with 2 separate GitHub workflows will result in 2 separate VMs booted up. If you setup tools or prepare things on VM 1, they will not be available on VM 2.

Answer (score 24):

The best method i've found for reusable workflows in the same repository is https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

In the workflow you want to re-use (let's call it `wf1`):

```yaml
# wf1.yml
on:
  workflow_call:
```

In the workflow you want to call `wf1` from (let's call this `wf2`)

```yaml
# wf2.yml
jobs:
  call-wf1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/wf1.yml
    secrets: inherit
```

---

In order to get data from one workflow to another, check out https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow.

First, set up your reusable workflow to output the data:

```yaml
name: Reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    # Map the workflow outputs to job outputs
    outputs:
      firstword:
        description: "The first output string"
        value: ${{ jobs.example_job.outputs.output1 }}
      secondword:
        description: "The second output string"
        value: ${{ jobs.example_job.outputs.output2 }}

jobs:
  example_job:
    name: Generate output
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map the job outputs to step outputs
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.firstword }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.secondword }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: echo "::set-output name=firstword::hello"
      - id: step2
        run: echo "::set-output name=secondword::world"
```

Now use it in the calling workflow:

```yaml
name: Call a reusable workflow and use its outputs

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job1:
    # local repo
    # uses: ./.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@v1
    # other repo
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@v1

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ needs.job1.outputs.firstword }} ${{ needs.job1.outputs.secondword }}
```

Comment: All the other methods require way too much setup and work.

Comment: Also, here's an example using this method: https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs-webui/blob/main/.github/workflows/node-versions.yml. This particular workflow is called on a schedule or manually via the github UI.

Comment: Worth mentioning, do NOT use `runs-on` on the same job that you called the workflow with `uses`

Comment: Ah, `secrets: inherit`. It just saved me from banging my head after 2 weeks of debugging without searching the internet. Upvoted!

Comment: Local repo paths must start with ./ and may not reference versions

Comment: The `uses` should be directly under the job. Not inside steps like I like an idiot did for several minutes :facepalm:.

Comment: Worth noting that matrix strategies will require you to specify flow2's inputs rather than specifying flow1's outputs.

Comment: @MikeB would you mind adding a section to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 14):

First, you are mixing terms here. According to [GitHub Actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) a single YAML file is called a **workflow** (not an action) and consists of **jobs**. Jobs contain a sequence of steps (including actions) that are executed one after another. A particular workflow execution is called a **run**. Having that in mind lets go the questions.

> How could the message **workflow** be triggered after build **workflow** is completed?

You can use GitHub API to trigger a webhook event called [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) (only for the base branch) or [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch). This can be easily done using a dedicated [Repository Dispach](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/repository-dispatch) action in your build workflow.

> Is it possible to get the result of the build **workflow**?

Yes, the result of the workflow run can be obtained using given [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow-runs/#get-a-workflow-run)

But if you only want to send the build result notification of the currently executed workflow you don't need to create a separate workflow and trigger it from the parent. You can use dedicated [Slack actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=slack) or [e-mail actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=email).

Comment: An example how the ymls would look would be great :)

Answer (score 11):

you can try in step 2 the following directive:

```
needs: step-1-job-name
```

just after job name

Comment: Is there a way to check multiple jobs success?

Comment: Yes, Vaulstein: "needs: [job1, job2]"
See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds

Answer (score 3):

> How could the message action be triggered after build action is completed?

This should now (August 2020) be possible with "[GitHub Actions improvements for fork and pull request workflows](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/)"

> Another frequently-requested feature for Actions is a way to trigger one workflow based on the completion of another workflow.
> For example, you may want to take the results of a CI workflow and run some further analysis.

> The new workflow_run event enables you to trigger a new workflow when one or more workflows are requested or completed.
> Runs triggered by the **`workflow_run`** event always use the default branch for the repository, and have access to a read/write token as well as secrets.
> As an example, as a maintainer you could set up a workflow that takes the artifacts generated by the pull request workflow, do some analysis, and post comments back to the pull request.
> This event is also available as a web hook.