# Is there a way to set up GitHub so that comment-only changes can be submitted without review?

Tags: github, bitbucket

Comments should not break any tests so the bar should be lowered to encourage more piecemeal check-ins. Does GitHub or any other code hosting platforms provide options to auto-detect the nature of the change, and adjust the number of required reviewers accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

First, comment can break any test relying on the size or number of line of a given file.

But assuming this is not the case, you would be looking at a GitHub Action like

- [`pascalgn/size-label-action`](https://github.com/pascalgn/size-label-action) able to assign label to a PR (you need to modify it in order to detect not the size of the code diff, but the presence of comments only)
- [`actions/label-requires-reviews`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/label-requires-reviews) able to assign, for a given label, the number of approved reviews needed on the Pull Request for the action to return a success value.

[Chain those two actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237192/6309) and you could influence that way the number of required reviewers.