# How can i get status of the last Github action run

Tags: github-actions, github-api

How can I get status of the last Github action run in order to use it in other workflow? I saw the option with REST but maybe there is another way how to do workflow that manually run only if status of another action successfully.

Answer (score 1):

> maybe there is another way how to do workflow that manually run only if status of another action successfully.

That is the [`wokrflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run=) trigger I [was mentioning here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237192/6309):

```
name: CI notify

# Only trigger, when the build workflow succeeded
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI build"]
    types:
      - completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bit old question but adding the solution i found for anyone in need here:
You can use a github action [Get status of last workflow](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-status-of-last-workflow)

```
jobs:
  yor-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get previous workflow status
        uses: Mercymeilya/last-workflow-status@v0.3.3
        id: last_status
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Any action
        run: slyle-check.sh

      - name: Build fixed slack message
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.1.3
        if: ${{ success() && steps.last_status.outputs.last_status == 'failure' }}
        env: 
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
          SLACK_MESSAGE: 'Style check fixed now!'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 - git log
```

git log [options] [revision-range] [[--] path​]

Git log is a utility tool to review and read a history of everything that happens to a repository.