# Github workflow not triggering on conditional branch name

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a job that I want to trigger for branches named `feat/<something>`, but I can't make it work.

If I name a branch `feat` and remove the `/` it works, but if I use `feat/test` it won't trigger

```
jobs:
  deploy_dev:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' && contains(github.ref_name, 'feat/')
    name: Deploy dev
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy-react.yml
    secrets:
      aws_role: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_DEV }}
      s3_bucket: ${{ secrets.S3_BUCKET_APP_DEV }}
      cloudfront_id: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFRONT_APP_DEV }}
      aws_access_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test first if the [alternative using filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-filters=) would work better:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'feat/**'
```

That way, no need to test `github.event_name` and `github.ref_name`.

Comment: Thanks, but that will not work. I already have branch filtering on the workflows, but some jobs on that flow are should run on specific branches.

Comment: @Stargazer Your existing job could call another job with that filter, as a [reusable workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72708636/6309)