# Triggering a workflow run after an action commits

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, git-commit

In a repository we have :

1. a workflow that runs `on: pull_request`
   so it runs each time I open/ commit to the pull-request (which I opened)
2. we have an action (runs manually) that commits to the pull-request (updating some files in the branch)

when the second action finishes to run, I can see its commit on the pull request
but it doesn't trigger the first workflow to run again
(in order to run the workflow after the action's commit, I need each time to insert a dummy commit or close and re-open the pull-request)
Is there another way to trigger the first workflow after a "bot" from the 2nd github action commits?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `push` trigger as well to the workflow as follows:

```
on:
  - push
  - pull_request
```

It should then run the workflow  when you push a commit or tag. See docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push).

Comment: currently my `on:` section is 
`push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:`

because we need it to run on every push to the master, how could I tell it that we want it to run on every push to `current branch` too?!

Comment: what if you removed branches section altogether to let it run on all  branches? Will that help your situation?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.  GitHub generally "dislike" having workflows trigger other workflows, for the obvious reason.<sup>1</sup>  Instead, write a [*reusable workflow*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), then use and re-use it.

See also [Github Actions - trigger another action after one action is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62750603/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>If the reason isn't obvious, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73632887/1256452).  Follow the link until it becomes obvious why this is a bad idea.  (In Computer Science, see the definition of [recursion](https://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/cs2mm/recursion.htm).  In Philosophy, a closely related idea is called [Begging the Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't help
I want to run the main workflow to see that the pull request is ready.
I have on the main workflow a: `push:     branches:       - master   pull_request:`
I need a way to add the current_branch to branches list (if there is one)

Comment: Reusable workflows take parameters: have the main workflow pass a parameter that says "main workflow on master" and have the pull request workflow pass a parameter that says "PR workflow on <branch>" (filling in the branch part) and have the reusable workflow use the *parameter*.