# Github action wait for cloud build to complete

Tags: github-actions, google-cloud-build

I trigger cloud build from github action (GHA) using gcloud command

```
  - name: Start CB trigger
    run: |
      export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
      gcloud beta builds triggers run iaisudh983u4923 --branch=main
```

Cloud build gets triggered asynchronously and GHA moves on. I would like GHA to wait for cloud build to finish processing and then based on whether cloud build succeeded or failed - GHA should proceed accordingly.

When I run the same `gcloud beta builds triggers` command locally - I get the same behavior. Command executes successfully without waiting for cloud build to finish executing.

Comment: Have you tried this [`jobs.<job\_id\>.needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) keyword? and also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698892/18265570).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following code we trigger cloud build from GHA and then wait for status to be anything other then "QUEUED" or "WORKING"

To allow GHA to view logs from cloud build - grant role `roles/logging.viewer` to gha service account.
This works only if logs are stored in logging and not in cloud storage bucket in the CB trigger yaml file

```
options:
 logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

GHA code:

```
  - name: Start CB trigger to deploy main branch to dev GAE
    run: |
      export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
      BUILD_ID=$(gcloud beta builds triggers run ${{ vars.DEPLOY_DJANGO_TRIGGER_ID_DEV_2 }} \
        --branch=$branch --quiet \
        --format="value(metadata.build.id)")
      
      echo "BUILD_ID = $BUILD_ID"
      gcloud beta builds log --stream "$BUILD_ID"
      BUILD_STATUS=$(gcloud builds describe $BUILD_ID --format="value(status)")
      echo "Build status = $BUILD_STATUS"
      
      if [ "$BUILD_STATUS" == "SUCCESS" ]; then
          exit 0
      else
          exit 1
      fi
```