# Trigger a Github workflow on PR and when another (one that triggers on commit) workflow is completed & successful

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow, "commit.yaml" (named "commit") that will trigger on push. (so, on every commit)
I have another that will only trigger on a pull request, but would like its job to depend on the outcome of the first workflow.

```yaml
# commit.yml
name: commit

on: [push]

jobs:
  build: [...]
```

and:

```yaml
# pull_request.yml
name: pull request

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [...]
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['commit']
    types: [completed]

jobs:
  jobA:
    if: |
      always() &&
      github.event.pull_request.draft == false &&
      github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
    uses: [...]
  jobB:
    if: |
      always() &&
      github.event.pull_request.draft == false &&
      github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
    uses: [...]
```

However, this doesn't work (jobA and jobB are automatically skipped). Is there any way I can achieve this..?

Comment: I believe the one that runs on pull_request will run on every commit you push to that pull_request. you dont need 2 separate workflows

Comment: yeah but I want the first one running on any commits, whether it's part of a PR or not. And I'd like the second one to run on PR only if the first one suceeded (I could re-run it, but that would duplicate jobs and waste resources for nothing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions - trigger another action after one action is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750603/github-actions-trigger-another-action-after-one-action-is-completed)

Comment: No it doesn't. I want to trigger another action after one is completed alright - but only when the PR even is also triggered (so essentially: I have two triggers, 1) the action and 2) the PR event). I don't know how to combine both cleanly without duplicating workflows...