# How to trigger a Github Actions workflow on push to another branch?

Tags: git, workflow, continuous-deployment, github-actions

When I push some code to `master`, one workflow file runs. This file builds the artifacts and pushes the code to another branch `production`.

Another workflow file, which looks like the following, is set to run when any push happens to `production`.

```yml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production

jobs:

# Do something

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master
```

But this workflow file is never run. I expect that when the workflow file, listening to push event on master, is done, this file should run as the previous file pushes code to `production` branch. How do I make sure that this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418323/triggering-a-new-workflow-from-another-workflow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a personal access token (PAT) for pushing the code in your workflow instead of the default `GITHUB_TOKEN`:

> Note: You cannot trigger new workflow runs using the `GITHUB_TOKEN`

> For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN`, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when `push` events occur.

> If you would like to trigger a workflow from a workflow run, you can trigger the event using a personal access token. You'll need to create a personal access token and store it as a secret.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#triggering-new-workflows-using-a-personal-access-token

```
name: Push to master

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # the checkout action persists the passed credentials by default
    # subsequent git commands will pick them up automatically
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{secrets.PAT}}
    - run: |
        # do something
        git push
```

Comment: Nice, this also works for protected branches to "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests". Just:

- 1. create a bot github account (to avoid using a personal access token)
- 2. create the PAT (on https://github.com/settings/tokens) for that bot account
- 3. Add the PAT to the repository secrets

Answer (score -2):

If anyone else stumbles upon this, it's actually git commit that is throwing an error. The '||' catches the error and then just prints to the log so the action doesn't even get to git push.

```
  - name: Scrape webpage and download file
    run: | 
      python ./python/scraper.py
      git config user.name github-actions
      git config user.email email@email.com
      git commit -am "Auto Generated" || echo "There is nothing to commit"
      git push
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34637469)

Comment: Take a look again at [answer]. This doesn't seem related to the question at hand, which is about an action not being triggered. There's no indication that the OP is even calling `git commit`