# Push event doesn't trigger workflow on push paths

Tags: github-actions

I'm currently testing GitHub Actions workflows on [this repository](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions). I'm trying to use [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/19-checkout-action.yml):

```
 on: 
   workflow_dispatch:
 
 jobs:
   job:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
       - uses: actions/checkout@v2
       - run: |
           date > report.txt
           git config user.name github-actions
           git config user.email github-actions@github.com
           git add .
           git commit -m "generate or update report.txt file"
           git push
```

to trigger [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/18-specific-file.yml):

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**/report.txt'

  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '**/report.txt'

jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Report .txt file has been updated"
```

I followed the [GitHub Actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) to implement the second workflow with a [filter pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet).

When I update the `report.txt` file locally, then commit and push the code to the repository, the second workflow triggers.

However, I don't understand why the second workflow doesn't trigger when the first workflow is completed, even with the `report.txt` file being updated on the default branch. Did I miss something on the first workflow to make it trigger the second, or should I add something on the second workflow to make it being triggered by the first one?

I know I could trigger the second workflow using other trigger event types (examples: `repository_dispatch` or `workflow_run`), but I'm trying to do it from a `git push` command on another workflow.

Comment: thanks to your comments that resolved that issue so I thought I'd say thanks

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triggering a new workflow from another workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418323/triggering-a-new-workflow-from-another-workflow)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you didn't miss anything in your workflows.

You just need a different token.

When you use [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout), it uses the `GITHUB_TOKEN` for authentication, and according to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow) it doesn't trigger a new workflow run:

> When you use the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN to perform tasks on behalf
> of the GitHub Actions app, events triggered by the GITHUB_TOKEN will
> not create a new workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally
> creating recursive workflow runs.

To make it work, you need to generate a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token), store it in your repository secrets, and use it in your checkout step:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.YOUR_PAT_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks :D I missed the point about the GITHUB_TOKEN not triggering a new workflow run.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

There are **three ways** of authentication within a GitHub action.

### 1. GITHUB_TOKEN

The [`GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) is always available and implicitly defined by GitHub.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

It has limited permissions, though, as it [cannot trigger new workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow). This is why your second workflow does not start.

### 2. PAT (Personal Access Token)

A [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) can be generated in your [developer settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens). You can then add it as an [encryped secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository), e.g. `PAT_TOKEN` to the GitHub project and use it instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
```

Subsequent push actions in the same workflow will then trigger any configured GitHub workflow as if they were pushed manually.

Be aware that the personal access token has access to **all** of your repositories and hence can be a potential security risk.

### 3. Deploy key

You can generate a dedicated SSH keypair and add it to the repository as a [Deploy Key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys). This is an alternative to the token-based authentication and has the same effect as the personal access token, but it only provides access to a single repository. It is done as follows:

1. Generate an SSH keypair:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -N "" -f deploy_key -C "github-actions"
   ```
2. Add the private key (generated file `deploy_key`) as an [encryped secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository), e.g. `COMMIT_KEY` to the GitHub project.

   [image: GitHub secret]
3. Add the public key (generated file `deploy_key.pub`) as a [deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#setup-2) with write access to the GitHub project. Tick the `Allow write access` checkbox.

   [image: Deploy key]
4. When checking out the source code in your workflow, add the SSH key:

   ```yaml
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     with:
       ssh-key: "${{secrets.COMMIT_KEY}}"
   ```