# How can I add a commit to a dependabot PR and run all checks?

Tags: github-actions, dependabot

I'm trying to bump the version on a repository when creating dependabot PR's. But ran into a few issues. I'm using the following workflow (summarized):

```
permissions:
  contents: write

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
      - name: bump version
        run: |
          ...
      - name: commit
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "dependabot[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "dependabot[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git commit -a -m "version update"
          git push
```

The issues which I ran into is that the new commit won't have any github actions ran on them. This means checks are not displayed as completed in the PR. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` **by design** doesn't trigger any workflows - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push event doesn't trigger workflow on push paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550727/push-event-doesnt-trigger-workflow-on-push-paths)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing to the correct docs. Adding the deploy key might work indeed. I'm not sure if it is the right solution though. I would expect that something as simple/common as changing the version in your repository when dependabot creates a pull request, shouldn't really need a work around like this. I don't even need the checks to run another time, I just expect the checks for the PR to be marked as passed instead of removed. That's why I was wondering if I was doing something wrong.