# GitHub workflow is not triggered after pushing tags?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow as below.

```
name: Releaser

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'
```

This workflow will be triggered when I manually push a new tag like `v1.1.1-rc1`. It works fine.

Now, I want to have another workflow to replace the "manually push".

```
name: sync-tags

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    paths:
      - TAGS

jobs:
  steps:
    - name: foo-example
      uses: foo-example
```

This workflow will be triggered when there's a change made in the `TAGS` directory. The jobs will create a new tag like `v1.1.1-rc1`. It works fine as well. But, after the `v1.1.1-rc1` is created by the `sync-tags`, the `Releaser` is not triggered.

I was wondering why the `Releaser` can be triggered by manually pushing tags but can't be triggered by tagging from other workflows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triggering a new workflow from another workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418323/triggering-a-new-workflow-from-another-workflow)

Answer (score 3):

I am having this same problem. It turns out this is [intentional behavior from GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

> … if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

Explicitly invoking the release workflow works! (Note: this needs GITHUB_TOKEN in the environment, which I happen to do for the entire workflow.)

```
      - name: New tag & launch release process
        run: |
          echo "Tagging $new_tag"
          git tag $new_tag
          git push --tags
          # Explicitly run our release workflow for this new tag
          gh workflow run release.yml --ref $new_tag
```

My release workflow needed to be enhanced to allow manual runs. The `workflow_dispatch:` line in the `on:` section.

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'
  workflow_dispatch:
```

To make sure we're building a release on a tag, I added `if: github.ref_type == 'tag'` to each job within the release workflow.

Comment: What permission did you use? I'm struggling with this.